# Create EJB with two interfaces. @Local interface for web module and @Remote interface for local app client

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, ejb, java-ee-6, ejb-3.1

I have a EAR package that contains a web module and EJB. The EJB is currently exposed its contains to local app client via `Remote` interface

```
@Stateless
public class CoreEJB implements CoreEJBRemote {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "CoreWeb-ejbPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public void packageProcess(String configFileName) throws Exception {
        //Process logics
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T create(T t) {
        em.persist(t);
        return t;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T find(Class<T> type, Object id) {
        return em.find(type, id);
    }

    ...
}
```

The `Remote` interface is not in EAR, and look like this

```
@Remote
public interface CoreEJBRemote {

    public void packageProcess(java.lang.String configFileName) throws java.lang.Exception;

    public <T extends java.lang.Object> T create(T t);

    public <T extends java.lang.Object> T find(java.lang.Class<T> type, java.lang.Object id);

}
```

The `Main` of the app client is below

```
public class Main {
    @EJB
    private static CoreEJBRemote coreEJB;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        coreEJB.packageProcess("path/to/a/file");
    }
}
```

Now i want to create an `Local` interface for the EJB so that in the `Managed Bean` of my web module, I can access the EJB via local invocation.

Do I just change `CoreEJB` from `public class CoreEJB implements CoreEJBRemote` to `public class CoreEJB implements CoreEJBRemote, CoreEJBLocal` and create `@Local` interface call `CoreEJBLocal` inside `EJB package`? Or will there be something extra? I want my Managed Bean code to be like this

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public void testView{
    @EJB
    private CoreEJBLocal coreEJB;

    public void add(Something something){
        coreEJB.add(something); //Local invocation
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I just change CoreEJB from public
>   class CoreEJB implements CoreEJBRemote
>   to public class CoreEJB implements
>   CoreEJBRemote, CoreEJBLocal and create
>   @Local interface call CoreEJBLocal
>   inside EJB package?

Yes, this should be sufficient.  Did you try?  Did it fail?  Keep in mind that local interfaces are pass-by-reference and remote interfaces are pass-by-value.  If callers (or the bean) mutate state on the return value (or arguments, respectively), then you're going to get different behavior between the two.  You must manage this careful in your API contract.

Comment: I have not try yet, these are sample codes that I wrote out to initiate my thought process. I want to know if it is possible. Now I read that GlassFish allow you to put `<pass-by-reference>true</pass-by-reference>` in `sun-ejb-jar.xml`. Do you happen to know where do I put this file at? In `META_INF`?

Comment: Yes, META-INF. Note that the setting can only affect co-located remote calls (calling an EJB in the same JVM); pure remote calls will still result in a copy.

Comment: Thank you. I have another question for. So now my EJB implements two interfaces (Remote and Local). And I have a method that I want to invoke both via Local and via Remote, is it ok to have both interface declare the same method. For some reasons, when I did that, netbeans warns `When a session bean has remote as well as local interface, there should not be any methods common to both the interfaces`. What do you think?

Comment: It should work.  I'm not familiar with NetBeans, so I don't know why it warns.  Perhaps for the same reason I described above (different calling conventions).