# Why "Warning: Common implementation for both interfaces" in Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, ejb

I am using Netbeans to create EJB 2.0 module. In this module, I created both local and remote interfaces. When I added business methods in the bean class, Netbeans allows conveniently to add to either local interface or remote interface or both. When I selected to add business methods in both local and remote interfaces, Netbeans shows a warning message: "`Warning: Common implementation for both interfaces`".

I do not understand what the problem it may cause if we have the same business methods in both local and remote interfaces??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6419560/create-ejb-with-two-interfaces-local-interface-for-web-module-and-remote-inter/6419852#6419852):

> Keep in mind that local interfaces are pass-by-reference and remote
>   interfaces are pass-by-value. If callers (or the bean) mutate state on
>   the return value (or arguments, respectively), then you're going to
>   get different behavior between the two. You must manage this careful
>   in your API contract.